# How to prevent accessing a web api from a web address

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-web-api

Sorry if the question is asked before. I searched but i can't find a way to solve my problem.

I have a web api (i don't use owin or something like that). The api creates task from data with sent by application and returns the taskId and pageId to application to pass it as get/post parameter to website. After that, The application that integrate the web api, redirect to one of my web application's page to complete the task created by my web api. I have some security flows such as appid-password to control accessed application. But this has some security problem.

If a customer share the appid and password with another person, then appid password info could use by a disallowed application.

Here is what i tried to solve the problem,
I tried to get `HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Origin"]` info but the application that entegrate my web api must send the header and it could not solve the problem. Because same "Origin" header can be sent by bunch of applications. I try to use the `HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["REMOTE_ADDR"]` or `HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["REMOTE_HOST"]` and both of returns the IP address of customer's application's IP Address. And these are could'not solve my problem too. Because in one server there may be thousands of applications. I tried to solve the Dns from an IP address but i could not achieve this because the entegrated application may not registered or it can't be accessible by outside network.

What is the best way to solve this problem? Thanks for helps.

Comment: Why are you worried about a customer sharing their details? Surely that is their problem?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Surely the sharing of customer info is their problem but the prevention of this is my problem. Because this is not an allowed situation.

Comment: So there is no User Information you collect while logging? So based on what your app expect to differentiate the users, if a single User id can be used by N number of user?

Comment: @lokanathdas Yes, There is no User Information. In fact i want to save the web address of application that entegrate my api, such as "www.abc.com" and i want to match the address with appid and password. This way, my api just accept the request from address that i saved as allowed addresses. But i could not find any way to get address that create request to web api.

Comment: Ok, then your api is upstream which is expected to get called/hooked with others apps right? then Let the app send the www.abc.com/www.xyz.com as a Api Request header(make it mandatory). If the api request header is Null or not matching your whitelist of Url then reject the APi request with Http500 error code. As your API shouldn't be worried who calls it, caller should take the responsibility of sending proper header to get authenticated.

Comment: @lokanathdas Yes you're right. I tried this but what if different apps send same Header? Because my api is using with a license fee per application.

Comment: Keep different user id for each app/URL. because it's not ideal design to share the same userid to every app. As in your case you don't have user info. so you need to keep some combination to verify the end Client. So Userid & the URL will be that combination.